# How to calculate cummulate no of days in postgresql with following condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table A

```
aid aname ano
1   Bulb  10
```

Table B

```
bid aid bno bdate
1   1   5   2/5/2017
2   1   3   5/5/2017
```

Table C

```
cid bid cno cdate
1   1   2   3/5/2017
2   1   2   5/5/2017
3   2   1   7/5/2017
4   1   1   8/5/2017
5   2   2   9/5/2017
```

Required Output

```
Name Total Days
Bulb 10    7
```

I have three tables in which Table A has a 1..n relation with Table B and Table C has a 1..n relation with Table B

Here i want cummulative no of days in which element aid was inserted in Table B and corresponding data was last retrieved from Table C and in my list element aname should appear only once along with cummulative no of days

Cummulative no of days should be calculated in such a way that bno=cno and `MAX(cdate) - MIN(bdate)`

How can i get the result in one query.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Table B and C will not join on `bno=cno` with this sample data, so how did you get this expected result?

Comment: Iam using Postgresql

Comment: Table B and C will not join on bno=cno only on bid=bid but MAX(cdate) must be at time when bno matches cno.

Comment: bno and cno not matches in example, so what is MAX(cdate) here ?

Comment: MAX(cdate) is 9/5/2017. Count(sum(cno)) on multiple rows must match with bno on bid=bid. ie on cid 1,2 & 4. Count(sum(cno)) = 5 which matches with bno on bid=1 and cid 3 & 5. Count(sum(cno)) = 3 which matches with bno on bid=2